# How use property expansion in a Launch4j config file

Tags: ant, build.xml, launch4j, variable-expansion

I use Launch4j and will use a property `${dist}` in its configuration.

It works when the task and it argument directly are in the `build.xml` file:

```
<project ...>
    <property name="dist" location="/temp/dist" />
    <launch4j>
        <config headerType="gui" outfile="${dist}/myprogram.exe"
            dontWrapJar="false" jarPath="${dist}/myprogram.jar">
            ...
        </config>
    </launch4j>

</project>
```

Launch4j can however use its own xml-configuration file, with `<launch4jConfig>` as root element:

in ant.xml:

```
<launch4j configFile="my_launch4j_config.xml" />
```

in my_launch4j_config.xml:

```
<launch4jConfig>
    <headerType>gui</headerType>
    <outfile>${dist}/myprogram.exe</outfile>
    <dontWrapJar>false</dontWrapJar>
        <jar>${dist}/myprogram.jar</jar>
        ...
</launch4jConfig>
```

In this case, `${dist}` is not expanded, nor `%dist%` or everything I tried... Does a solution exist to use properties in an launch4j config file?

Comment: You might want to "expand" your template before using it `config.xml` by copying with filterset. For an example, see http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterset.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code of launch4j did not accept such replacements of parameters, but I could change this behaviour (modifications to `net.sf.launch4j.config.ConfigPersister`). I check it in the Sourceforge project when I have enough time for it.

Comment: I will actually not check this change as it introduces some undesirable dependance of `ConfigPersiser` with `ant`. The better will be the [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26714942/how-use-property-expansion-in-a-launch4j-config-file/26717871#comment42020691_26714942) of @halfbit